# How to check if CURTIME() is in between 2 different times?

Tags: mysql, time, between

I am trying to do a time check using MySQL to see if the current time falls between 2 given timestamps or not.

What I am trying to do is to generate a notification list if the set notification range is in between the 2 given timestamps.

So if someone said notify me via TXT message between '18:00:01' AND '07:59:59' THEN notify me via EMAIL BETWEEN '18:00:01' AND '07:59:59'.

**Here is what I have done.**

So I have tried the following (assuming current time is 17:00:00)

```
SELECT CURTIME() BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '18:00:00' //this retured 1 which is correct
```

However if when I tried the following (assuming current time is 19:00:00)

```
SELECT CURTIME() BETWEEN '18:00:01' AND '07:59:59'  //this return 0
```

This is my current query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
TRIM(su.first_name) AS name,
CASE WHEN n.notification_method = "SMS" THEN 
CASE WHEN cc.gateway IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(su.phone_cell, cc.gateway) ELSE "" END
ELSE su.email1 END AS address
FROM  ticketing_system_notifications AS n
INNER JOIN(
SELECT DISTINCT created_by, issue_id FROM ticketing_system_discussions
WHERE status = 1
) AS ds ON n.notify = ds.created_by
INNER JOIN users AS su ON su.user_id = n.notify
LEFT JOIN cell_phone_carriers AS cc ON cc.carrier_id = su.carrier_id
WHERE ds.issue_id = 31 AND n.notify <> 12 AND n.notification_type = "REPLY"
AND n.category_id = 0 AND n.status = 1 AND (n.expired_on IS NULL OR n.expired_on > NOW() ) 

AND (  (n.start IS NULL OR n.end IS NULL) OR (  

CASE WHEN n.start <= n.end THEN
CURTIME() BETWEEN n.start AND n.end
ELSE
CURTIME() >= n.start AND CURTIME() <= n.end
END   )  )
```

This is where I am going wrong

```
CASE WHEN n.start <= n.end THEN
CURTIME() BETWEEN n.start AND n.end
ELSE
CURTIME() >= n.start AND CURTIME() <= n.end
END   )
```

Can someone please help me building the logic to capture the time correctly?
Both the fields `start` and `end` are of type `TIME`

In my `ticketing_system_notifications` table I have the following 2 records
1) `start` = '08:00:00' `end` = '18:00:00' TEXT
2) `start` = '17:59:59' `end` = '07:59:59'

Comment: You'll need to work with the dates, too, if you're wrapping around midnight

Comment: Use full dates for your comparison.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the time range wraps over midnight you should use this logic instead:

```
 curtime() >= n.start OR curtime() <= n.end
```

Think about it: the current time has to be between the "start" and midnight, OR between the midnight and the "end."

Comment: I believe you are correct. when I change that I got the value that I was looking for. Thank you so much :)

Comment: +1: After going thru lot of forums, this one finally worked for me.

Comment: For current time as '00:00:01' and start and end times are '03:00:00' and '04:00:00' respectively, then it returns true which is wrong.

Comment: There is a typo in this (old? and accepted) answer. code should be: `curtime() >= n.start AND curtime() <= n.end`  (so, **AND**, and not `OR`).

Comment: Luuk & sushil: The question is about the scenario where the *time range wraps midnight* and `end` is before `start`. For example, start = 22:00 and end = 08:00.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

> SELECT *  FROM test1  WHERE '00:00:01' BETWEEN startt AND endt

Comment: It would be better to comment on the accepted answer, and state why that answer is incorrect that spamming another answer without comments.

Comment: Ok, I will do, thanks